# How can I make tcsh's "postcmd" not execute typed command if the postcmd command fails?

Tags: tcsh

In bash, when I implement precmd() functionality via `trap ??? DEBUG`, I can make the typed command fail to execute, if the command in precmd() call returns non-zero return code; by using `set -o functrace` and `shopt -s extdebug`.

I'm trying to implement similar functionality in tcsh via `postcmd` alias in tcsh. However, I was unable to find any details in tcsh documentation on how to do the same thing as in bash (if the command in `postcmd` fails and returns non-zero RC, don't execute the command typed at the prompt).

## How can I achieve that effect in tcsh?

*Desired outcome:*

```
# Set up postcmd alias to check of current user is "OK" (in OK file)
MYUSER:~> alias postcmd 'grep $USER /tmp/ok_users > /dev/null'

# Add myself to OK list  (in another xterm)
MYUSER:~> echo "$USER" > ! /tmp/ok_users
MYUSER:~> cat /tmp/ok_users
MYUSER

MYUSER:~> grep $USER /tmp/ok_users | wc -l; echo $?
1
0

# Run command - expect it to succeed:
MYUSER:~> echo TEST2
TEST2  # <==== As expected

##########
# Now, let's make sure I'm NOT in OK users (in another xterm).

MYUSER:~> echo "junk" > ! /tmp/ok_users
MYUSER:~> cat /tmp/ok_users
junk
MYUSER:~>  grep $USER /tmp/ok_users | wc -l ; echo $?
0
1

# Now, what I need is, for my typed command to NOT be executed
#     due to "postcmd" hook command (grep) failing

MYUSER:~> echo TEST2
MYUSER:~> <==== Want to NOT echo anything. How do I do that?
```

*I'd prefer the answer to be OS portable, but if required, at least it must work on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6*

Comment: FWIW, `alias postcmd 'kill -s INT 0'` seems to work for builtin commands (including `eval non-builtin-command`). If you want the best of ksh/bash and tcsh, you may want to consider zsh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - are you posting this as an answer? if no, I think I developed an answer based on your idea and will post myself

Comment: No, I'm not, please go ahead.